# Sharing a service through filter between two controllers doesn't work in angular 1.3.x

Tags: angularjs, migration

OK guys Im pretty sure its documented somewhere but I cannot seem to locate it, this is why I apologize in advance if its already been discussed.

Im trying to share a localization service through a filter across different controllers/directives etc.
In angular 1.2.x it was working, but in 1.3.x it doesnt.

See [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YJor3h1kjiP0wzVwwjF2?p=preview)
Uncomment the script to switch between 1.2.x/1.3.x

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('trnsService', ['$rootScope',
  function($rootScope) {
    var trnsService = {},
      trns = {
        'CONSTANT': {
          'en': 'En text',
          'bla': 'Bla text'
        }
      },
      lan = 'en';

    trnsService.setLang = function setLang(lang) {
      lan = lang;

      console.log(lan);

      if (!$rootScope.$$phase) {
        $rootScope.$apply();
      }
    };

    trnsService.getTrns = function getTrns(key) {
      return trns[key][lan]
    };
    return trnsService;
  }
])
  .filter('trns', ['trnsService',
    function(trnsService) {
      return function(input) {
        return trnsService.getTrns(input);
      };
    }
  ])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, trnsService) {
    $scope.setLang = function setLang(lg) {

      trnsService.setLang(lg);
    }
  })
  .controller('SecCtrl', function($scope, trnsService) {
    $scope.setLang = function setLang(lg) {

      trnsService.setLang(lg);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Setting the filter as $stateful did it for me. Just wish I found it earlier and havent lost entire day on it...

```
.filter('trns', ['trnsService',
    function(trnsService) {
      // return function(input) {
      //   return trnsService.getTrns(input);
      // };
      function decorateFilter(input) {
        return trnsService.getTrns(input);
      }
      decorateFilter.$stateful = true;
      return decorateFilter;
    }
  ])
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MPdJ8CZLk6rrtVkAiZ3W?p=preview)

Some more info here:

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/720

and here

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter